# Xcode error "Dependencies could not be resolved", but only when building via command line

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a project that builds perfectly fine from within Xcode, but it fails when I want to run it from the command line. I get this error:

`error: Dependencies could not be resolved because no versions of 'pathkit' match the requirement 1.0.1..<2.0.0 and root depends on 'saga' 1.1.3..<2.0.0. 'saga' >= 1.1.3 practically depends on 'pathkit' 1.0.1..<2.0.0 because 'saga' 1.1.3 depends on 'pathkit' 1.0.1..<2.0.0 and no versions of 'saga' match the requirement 1.1.4..<2.0.0.`

I'm not sure what's going on, as pathkit 1.0.1 exist and works fine. Here's a screenshot from Xcode, where I have no problems at all:

[image]

I've already removed all derived data.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I removed the project, did a clean checkout from git, and now it works again ‍♂️